# DWT feature Extraction

Tags: feature-extraction, dwt

I am working on ECG signals for human identification.i want to extract features from ecg signal using discrete wavelet transform. how I can extract feature from ecg signal. can anyone help me for extracting features?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Muhammad Sheharyar Asif.  Could you describe what you mean by "features"? The DWT transform will allow you to break your input signal into different scales: is this what you are referring to?

Comment: In any case, I would suggest playing with `scipy`'s ECG dataset: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.electrocardiogram.html